# Poetry install fails with 'ChefBuildError' Backend 'poetry.cor.masonry.api' is not available

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I have made my own python package with Poetry version 1.4.2 with:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

In another package, also setup with poetry (version 1.4.2), I depend on this package. If I run `poetry install` locally then everything is fine. However, when installing as a Dockerfile build step I get the following error:

```
ChefBuildError

Backend 'poetry.core.masonry.api' is not available.
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used pip to install poetry version 1.4.2 I got the error mentioned.
Switching to installing poetry using the following command fixes the issue:

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_VERSION=1.4.2 python3 -
```

It is unclear to me why this fixes the problem, feel free to amend my answer with an explanation.